# WebDeployment to godaddy host fail in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have small 2 view app developed for test purpuroses in ASP.NET MVC with visual studio 2015 comunity.

I tried to deploy app with publish wizzard from visual studio, same way i did with VS 2013 and same host, but some errors occur when i try to publish it.

First, when i click on validate connection, everything goes fine.
When i try to "preview changes" before publish, i got an "ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED", and when i try to skip preview, and publish app without it, error is "ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED".

Also, when i try to execute command line , error is "ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE"...

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to edit the pubxml file (Located at PROJECT\PublishProfiles) and add `<AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>` into the `<PropertyGroup>` element? I had the same problemn and solved by doing so.

The error for me has begun when the server certificate was not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought it relative to update since this was partially a true solution for me. Adding the AllowUntrustedCertificate could work all by itself, but in my case, both VS 2015 and 2017 still threw an error about ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE. I was using the PLESK version of the Web Publishing configuration and it was wrong. PLESK doesn't appear to take some security settings in play when configuring your settings to import into VS. Downloading directly from the GoDaddy hosting site, the configuration was setting the server as the website address. With the Firewall enabled, I needed to change the server in my publishing settings from wwww.whatever.com to 11.11.111.111 (your actual IP here). As soon as I did that, I was able to validate the connection, and with the AllowUntrustedCertificate tag in the Properties Group, I was able to connect and publish.

Bottom line. Is Firewall Enabled? Try some other configuration changes in your publish settings and see if that allows you to connect.